# Android Lint Error "Can't find API database; API check not performed"

Tags: android, android-lint

When running Android Lint it outputs the following error "Can't find API database; API check not performed"

Answer (score 1):

I found this is an issue if the Lint tool cannot find the Android sdk. The solution is to either set your ANDROID_HOME environment variable or to manually set the "sdk home" argument when calling the tool

```
.\lint.bat myapp --sdk-home "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk"
```

Comment: What is the fix in Ubuntu, please?