# How to fix Gradle build error : Can't find API database; API check not performed [LintError] in Ubuntu?

Tags: android, ubuntu, gradle, build.gradle

It's basically the same question as the one asked here:
[Android Lint Error "Can't find API database; API check not performed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52867478/android-lint-error-cant-find-api-database-api-check-not-performed)
but for Ubuntu, I didn't find how to adapt the answer given to Windows users.

I don't have Eclipse or Android Studio, I just installed gradle and android-sdk. I am trying to follow the tutorial there :
https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/08/10/basic-android-without-an-ide

I get this error after typing "gradle build".

Comment: I found a workaround here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31568610/disable-lint-in-android-gradle